# CImageList scope vs CImageList::ExtractIcon() returned HICON scope

Tags: bitmap, mfc, scope, icons, imagelist

I have used CImageList for converting bitmap to HICON and I am wondering is HICON returned by CImageList::ExtractIcon() still valid after CImage destruction? Lets assume I have code like this:

```
HICON Icon;

        {
            CImageList ImageList;
            ...
            Icon = ImageList.ExtractIcon(0);
        }

Icon;//<----------- Is this still valid?
```

In GUI I can see that it shows correct bitmap as icon and everythig works as expected but when I checked in debugger the returned HICON by ::GetIconInfo it always returns false even when the CImageList still exists. Any ideas? Is the HICON in code above correct after closing braces or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely safe to do it like you do. The `CImageList::ExtractIcon()` method calls `ImageList_ExtractIcon()` macro which does call the `ImageList_GetIcon()` function to create an icon or cursor based on an image and mask in an image list. Don't forget to call `DestroyIcon()` when you no longer need this icon.

The other way of doing it is the following:

```
HICON HICONFromCBitmap(CBitmap& bitmap)
{
   BITMAP bmp;
   bitmap.GetBitmap(&bmp);

   HBITMAP hbmMask = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(::GetDC(NULL), 
                                              bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight);

   ICONINFO ii = {0};
   ii.fIcon    = TRUE;
   ii.hbmColor = bitmap;
   ii.hbmMask  = hbmMask;

   HICON hIcon = ::CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
   ::DeleteObject(hbmMask);

   return hIcon;
}
```

Comment: I already find that out but forgot to post an answer here, thank you!